# Iterate through each row of CSV and write into individual JSON files in a folder using Python-Pandas

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I am trying to generate separate JSON files for every row using the input as CSV and save in to output folder. Using loop logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `data` is a dictionary defined in your question, the following code could do what you are looking for:

```
data_path = 'C:/Users/usasxs174/Desktop/ETL/Data_tables/MT/'
for i, data_item in enumerate(data['entities']):
    with open(data_path + str(i) + '.json', 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write(json.dumps(data_item, indent=4))
```

Comment: Thank you. However i am looking for converting 'data' dict  in to separate json files.

Comment: @satyaveni, I have edited the code. Now, it saves data from `data` dictionary in `for` loop to separate JSON files. In case it is not what you are looking for, please, edit your question in order to specify the desired output of every JSON file.

Comment: I am glad I could help.

Comment: Try to replace last row of my code for this row: `outfile.write(json.dumps({'entities': [data_item]}, indent=4))`. Is it your desired output?